# One jquery function for opening different box on hover different button

Tags: jquery, html

I have a code that opens different box on hovering different box. I am using jquery for that but it is opening only one box on first button my code is as follows:

```
<!--buttons are as follows-->

<div style="width:190px; height:415px; float:left;">
  <input type="button" id="menubut" class="but5" value="Women products " />
  <input type="button" id="menubut" class="but6" value="Kids products " />
  <input type="button" id="menubut" class="but7" value="Grocery products " />
  <input type="button" id="menubut" class="but8" value="Loan products " />
</div> 



<!--boxes are as follows-->
<div style="margin-left:190px; margin-top:10px; position:relative;">
    <div class="box1">
        <h1> BOX 1</h1> </div>
    <div class="box2">
        <h1> BOX 2</h1> </div>
</div>





$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#menubut").mouseenter(function() {
        var num = $(this).attr('class');
        alert(num);
        $(".box" + num).css("display", "block");
    });
    $("#menubut").mouseleave(function() {
        var num = $(this).attr('class');
        $(".box" + num).css("display", "none");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a single id for any given element. When you have two or more elements sharing the same id, only the first will be considered. I've changed all buttons to have the same class `.menubut` and changed the id's to unique identifiers. I also added two more boxes changed the boxes from having a class to an id and now they have a matching button to show/hide the corresponding box.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".menubut").mouseenter(function() {
        // Get the last character of the id
        var num = $(this).attr('id').slice(-1);
        // Hide that box
        $("#box" + num).hide();
    });
    $(".menubut").mouseleave(function() {
        // Get the last character of the id
        var num = $(this).attr('id').slice(-1);
        // Show that box
        $("#box" + num).show();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--buttons are as follows-->

<div style="width:190px; height:415px; float:left;">
<input type="button" class="menubut" id="but1" value="Women products " />
<input type="button" class="menubut" id="but2" value="Kids products " />
<input type="button" class="menubut" id="but3" value="Grocery products " />
<input type="button" class="menubut" id="but4" value="Loan products " />
</div> 



<!--boxes are as follows-->
<div style="margin-left:190px; margin-top:10px; position:relative;">
    <div id="box1">
        <h1> BOX 1</h1> </div>
    <div id="box2">
        <h1> BOX 2</h1> </div>
    <div id="box3">
        <h1> BOX 3</h1> </div>
    <div id="box4">
        <h1> BOX 4</h1> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this :
ID's are unique and Classes are NOT unique

```
        <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
    <script> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".buttton").mouseenter(function(){
                 var num = $(this).attr('id');               
                 $("#box" + num).hide();
                });
            $(".buttton").mouseleave(function(){
                 var num = $(this).attr('id');
                $("#box" + num).show();
               });
            });
        </script>
        <div style="width: 190px; height: 415px; float: left;">
            <input type="button" id="1" class="buttton"value="Women products " /> 
            <input type="button" id="2"  class="buttton" value="Kids products " /> 
            <input type="button" id="3" class="buttton" value="Grocery products " /> 
            <input type="button" id="4" class="buttton" value="Loan products " />
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left:190px; margin-top:10px; position:relative;">
                <div id="box1">
                    <h1> BOX 1</h1> </div>
                <div id="box2">
                    <h1> BOX 2</h1> </div>
               <div id="box3">
                    <h1> BOX 3</h1> </div>
                <div id="box4">
                    <h1> BOX 4</h1> </div>       
            </div>
    </body> 
    </html>
```